# How to make dupli objects the same size as parent object faces?

Tags: modeling

Inherit scale has to be set so that when I scale individual faces of parent mesh, the dupli objects are kept the same size as scaled faces of the parent mesh.

[image]

---

In these screenshots, the parent mesh object has 3 differently scaled faces (orange) and the child object blue.

- Left side:

  Inherit scale is 0.25 and it's too small, blue duplicates are much smaller than parent mesh object faces.
- Right side:
  Inherit scale is 0.5 and it gives the desired result, blue dupli objects are exactly the same sizes as parent mesh object faces:

[image]

Given any shape, how do I calculate the correct *inherit scale* value to make the dupli objects the same size as the parent object's faces?

Comment: Please clarify. your question is hard to understand. Add a visual example or write in more 'down to earth' terms.

Comment: Is this still [on hold] ?

Comment: I think I understand what you want. It seems blender probably calculate the area of the parent face in (BU**2)/2 (BU=blender units) and the inherit scale is based on that. So if you have a parent's face that is a square with the side being 2BU then the area would be 4BUˆ2 and it would scale your duplicate by 4(BUˆ2)/2=2. If you set the inherit scale to 1, then scale of the duplicate is multiplied by2. So it makes sens that you need to set the inherit scale to 0.5 to obtain a scale of 1. I'm really not sure of the exact calcul blender does but you can try with your pentagone to see if it works.